Conda environment in docker
I am new to dockerization and I am trying to make a docker image out of git repository. The Dockerfile looks like this,
FROM continuumio/miniconda3:latest
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

WORKDIR /fire_danger_tool
COPY . /fire_danger_tool/.
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "--login", "-c"]
RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y build-essential gfortran
RUN conda init
RUN conda create -p /fire_danger_tool/env/fireml python=3.10
RUN echo "conda activate /fire_danger_tool/env/fireml" > ~/.bashrc
RUN conda install -c conda-forge mamba
RUN mamba init
RUN mamba install -c conda-forge gdal cython cf-units=3.2.0 esmpy
    WORKDIR /fire_danger_tool/frameworks/geokube/
RUN python setup.py install
WORKDIR /fire_danger_tool
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/pip \
    --mount=type=bind,source=requirements.txt,target=requirements.txt \
    python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN cp -f /fire_danger_tool/env/fireml/lib/libstdc++.so.6 /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
RUN python -c "from geokube.core.datacube import DataCube"
WORKDIR /fire_danger_tool/frameworks/kit4dl/
RUN pip install -e .
WORKDIR /fire_danger_tool
ARG UID=10001
RUN adduser \
    --disabled-password \
    --gecos "" \
    --home "/nonexistent" \
    --shell "/sbin/nologin" \
    --no-create-home \
    --uid "${UID}" \
    appuser

USER appuser

EXPOSE 8000

CMD python src/inference.py --date=2018-08-20 --conf=src/config/inference_config.toml --collect_data --prepare_static
    
    ARG UID=10001
    RUN adduser \
        --disabled-password \
        --gecos "" \
        --home "/nonexistent" \
        --shell "/sbin/nologin" \
        --no-create-home \
        --uid "${UID}" \
        appuser
    
    
    USER appuser
    
    EXPOSE 8000
    
    CMD python src/inference.py --date=2018-08-20 --conf=src/config/inference_config.toml --collect_data --prepare_static

The docker image is created without error. But when I run the docker image, it seems that the conda environment is not already activated in the image. Moreover, conda has not been initiated. I need the conda environment because one of the libraries I need is only available in conda or to be installed from the source. Installing the said library from the source had its own problems.
Is there a way to create a docker image with the conda environment already activated?
